# What is const char* for Python3

Tags: python, swig

A function in C is as following:

```
char* test(const char* input, size_t length);
```

use swig(3.0.2) to export to python extension.

In python2, run `test("hello",len("hello"))`, the function works quite well.

But in python 3, run `config="hello";test(config.encode("utf-8"),len(config.encode("utf-8")))`

```
TypeError: in method 'test', argument 0 of type 'char const *'
```

How can I use this function in Python3?

Comment: I'm not a Swig expert, but probably you have to play with one of the `%pybuffer_*` macros: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn75 (most likely you need `%pybuffer_binary`).

Answer (score 0):

I find out the real reason.

In python 3, I should use the same thing as in python2. That is to say `test("hello",len("hello"))`

But Python3 the len("hello") will not be right for real UTF-8.

For example,

python2:

```
>>>len("测试")
4
```

python3:

```
>>>len("测试")
2
```

So the C function get a wrong length.

Answer (score -1):

In C `const char *` is a type for **immutable** `char *` (string). I am not sure why you get that error - might be because you are passing a Python string which is **mutable** - you can modify/reassign it:

```
config = "hello"
config = config[:2]
```

Comment: Strings in Python are immutable. You create a new string. You do not modify it. Check the id of `config` with `id(config)` before and after your new assignment.

Comment: Python str is immutable. And you maybe need to learn about it. You can try config[0]+=1, and you'll get an error.

Comment: Like @MikeMüller, said, String are IMMUTABLE